# Упростить код создания массивов

Tags: java, android

Поскажите пожалуйста, можно ли упростить такой код? Или так и писать на 20 Case?

```
ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_0 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_1 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_2 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_3 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_4 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_5 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_6 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_7 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_8 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_9 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_10 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_11 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_12 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_13 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_14 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_15 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_16 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_17 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_18 = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_19 = new ArrayList();

    //цикл на 20 карт
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        String FileName = mapsActivity.myFolder_Points + "/" + mapsActivity.arr_namePointsTxtFile[i];
        try {
            Scanner Scnr = new Scanner(new File(mapsActivity.Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Points_in_Map,
                    FileName)).useDelimiter("\n");
            while (Scnr.hasNext()) {
                String[] Cols = Scnr.next().split("﹀");
                try {
                    switch (i) {
                        case (0):
                            gallery_arr_0.add(new String[2]);
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_0.get(gallery_arr_0.size() - 1))[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_0.get(gallery_arr_0.size() - 1))[1] = Cols[4]; // грузим изображения
                            break;
                        case (1):
                            gallery_arr_1.add(new String[2]);
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_1.get(gallery_arr_1.size() - 1))[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_1.get(gallery_arr_1.size() - 1))[1] = Cols[4]; // грузим изображения
                            break;
                        case (2):
                            gallery_arr_2.add(new String[2]);
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_2.get(gallery_arr_2.size() - 1))[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_2.get(gallery_arr_2.size() - 1))[1] = Cols[4]; // грузим изображения
                            break;
                        case (3):
                            gallery_arr_3.add(new String[2]);
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_3.get(gallery_arr_3.size() - 1))[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера
                            ((String[]) gallery_arr_3.get(gallery_arr_3.size() - 1))[1] = Cols[4]; // грузим изображения
                            break;
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }

    }
```

ДЕЛАЮ ТАК:

```
public class MyObject {
    String name, imgUrl;
    String[] params;

    public MyObject(){
        params = new String[20];
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }
}


.........

myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    //цикл на 20 карт
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        String FileName = mapsActivity.myFolder_Points + "/" + mapsActivity.arr_namePointsTxtFile[i];
        try {
            Scanner Scnr = new Scanner(new File(mapsActivity.Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Points_in_Map,
                    FileName)).useDelimiter("\n");
            while (Scnr.hasNext()) {
                String[] Cols = Scnr.next().split("﹀");

                    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
                    myObject.setName(Cols[1]);
                    myObject.setImgUrl(Cols[4]);
                    myObjects.add(myObject);

            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }

    }



    mapsActivity.z_Timer.textview_test.setText(myObjects.get(1).getName());
```

Но получается только по одной строке выводить.. Подправьте по точнее пожалуйста, весь пример..

Comment: Сделайте массив списков

Comment: А примерчик можно если не трудно?

Comment: Он имеет ввиду, нужно использовать динамические массивы типа  List, ArrayList. Тогда вам будет не нужны `ArrayList<String[]> gallery_arr_1 = new ArrayList();` а просто List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); и добавлять вместо `((String[]) gallery_arr_2.get(gallery_arr_2.size() - 1))[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера`  на `ints.add(Cols[1]);`

Comment: А у меня какие? Есть 20 тхт файлов, в каждом файле от 1 до 1000 строк с параметрами, надо это все загрузить в массивы или списки, в общем чтобы можно было легко добраться до каждого.. Я могу и 20 раз код case повторить, но если бы было 100 и больше файлов, тогда как?

Comment: Если вам не нужно фильтровать информацию из txt файлов, то еще проще и не нужно case использовать.

Comment: У меня строки с двумя параметрами, Cols[1] и Cols[4].. Причем параметров потом может быть и больше.. В общем пока не понял..

Comment: Вы хотите достать из каждого файла текст и картинку и сгруппировать полученные данные?

Comment: Да, в каждом файле строки с параметрами через разделитель.. Файлов 20. Я в цикле имена файлов меняю если заметили.. Надо занести эти строки с параметрами, чтобы потом можно было обратиться к одному из 20, и получить любой параметр любой строки в листе.. Пока два параметра, Cols[1] и Cols[4]..

Comment: Вы использовали коллекции?

Answer (score 2):

Упростить Ваш код можно - обернуть все списки ещё в один список, массив или, как уже советовали, в `Map` (если нужно и проще обращаться по ключу, а не по индексу).
Пример со списком:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> galleries = new ArrayList<>();

//цикл на 20 карт
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    String FileName = mapsActivity.myFolder_Points + "/" + mapsActivity.arr_namePointsTxtFile[i];
    try {
        Scanner Scnr = new Scanner(new File(mapsActivity.Directory_Catalog_of_pathFilesTXT_Points_in_Map,
                    FileName)).useDelimiter("\n");
        ArrayList<String[]> gallery = new ArrayList<>();
        while (Scnr.hasNext()) {
            try {
                String[] Cols = Scnr.next().split("﹀");
                String[] strings = new String[2];
                strings[0] = Cols[1]; // грузим название маркера
                strings[1] = Cols[4]; // грузим изображения
                gallery.add(strings);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        galleries.add(gallery);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

В случае с кастомным классом-моделью - заменяем `String[] strings` на него.

**UPDATE:** получение значений:

```
String[] strings = galleries.get(indexOfFile).get(indexOfLine);
```

Дальше думаю Вы знаете. И не забываем, что индексы считаются с нуля.

Comment: Спасибо, а как из вашего примера получить нужное значение, указав номер списка(1 из 20), потом номер строки и номер переменной?

Comment: @Alex455, Добавил в ответ

Comment: Попробовал Ваш пример, у меня не ищет маркеры по спискам.. Они просто подряд идут.. Где нужно указывать номер списка(1 из 20) ?  Вот как я вывожу названия маркера: String[] strings = galleries.get(0).get(0);
        mapsActivity.z_Timer.textview_test.setText(strings[0]);

Comment: Перевожу на русский:) `galleries.get(номерСписка).get(номерСтроки)`

Comment: Тогда где-то ошибка, потому что при таком варианте он показывает вторую строку первого списка, а не первую строку второго списока.. String[] strings = galleries.get(1).get(0);
        mapsActivity.z_Timer.textview_test.setText(strings[0]);

Comment: Да, действительно ошибка - что-то я забыл про внутренний цикл... Сейчас должно быть как надо.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Ваш пример пока единственный, что получилось сделать..

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит заводить отдельные переменные для хранения данных из разных файлов, и не стоит использовать `case` таким образом. Не нужно также описывать мелкую возню с чтением файлов прямо в том коде, который будет пользоваться этими данными -- лучше вынести это в отдельные методы. 
Иначе код получается громоздким, его трудно понимать и трудно будет изменить в случае изменения требований к программе.

Данные из всех файлов можно хранить в одной структуре, это может быть массив списков, или список списков, или специально созданный класс для хранения (и, может быть, какой-то обработки) ваших данных. Соображения, высказанные `Jarvis_J` в соседнем ответе, вполне резонны -- структура фалов может измениться, и вам могут понадобиться дополнительные поля -- в этом случае лучше создать специальные классы.

По существу же вопроса -- конкретных вариантов может быть много, выбор наилучшего зависит от конкретной задачи и ваших предпочтений, вот один из возможных:

```
  // Названия ваших файлов, можно получить список имен файлов  
  // из директории или как-то еще
  String[] fileNames = { 
    "file_01", "file_02", // ... Сколько надо
  };    

  // Вот это будут данные, класс DataCollection описан ниже  
  DataCollection fileData;

  void doTheWork() { // Собственно работа с данными 
    // Загружаем файлы: 
    fileData = new DataCollection(fileNames);

    // Имя маркера и имя изображения из 10-го элемента 5-го файла:
    System.out.println(fileData.getMarkerName(5, 10));
    System.out.println(fileData.getImgName(5, 10));
  }

  // Класс, который хранит данные и делает всю работу с ними
  class DataCollection {

    // Конструктор загружает данные из файлов
    public DataCollection(String[] fileNames) {
      for (String fileName: fileNames)
        fileData.add(loadFile(fileName));
    }


    public String getMarkerName(int fileIdx, int itemIdx) {
      return getItem(fileIdx, itemIdx).getMarkerName();
    }

    public String getImgName(int fileIdx, int itemIdx) {
      return getItem(fileIdx, itemIdx).getImgName();
    }

    // Остальные детали извне не видны 
    // и внешним кодом не используются
    private class DataItem { // Это один элемент данных
      private String markerName, imgName;

      // Конструктор создает объект данных с полученными значениями
      DataItem(String markerName, String imgName) { 
        this.markerName = markerName;
        this.imgName = imgName;
      }

      String getMarkerName() { return markerName; }
      String getImgName() { return imgName; }
    }

    // Собственно коллекция с данными:  
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<DataItem>> fileData = new ArrayList<>(); 



    // Данные читаются из одного файла и возвращаются в виде списка 
    private ArrayList<DataItem> loadFile(String fileName) {
      ArrayList<DataItem> data = new ArrayList<>();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName)).useDelimiter("\n");
      while (scanner.hasNext()) {   // Собственно чтение
        String[] Cols = scanner.next().split("﹀");
        data.add(new DataItem(Cols[1], Cols[4])); // Новый элемент данных
      };
      scanner.close();      // Не забывать!
      return data;
    }

    // Получить элемент данных
    private DataItem getItem(int fileIdx, int itemIdx) {
      if (fileIdx < 0 || fileIdx >= fileData.size()) 
        throw new Exception("Нет файла # " + fileIdx);
      if (itemIdx < 0 || itemIdx >= fileData.size()) 
        throw new Exception("В файле # " + fileIdx + " нет элемента # " + itemIdx);
      return fileData.get(fileIdx).get(itemIdx);
    }

  } // static class DataCollection {
```

Это только скелет, схема, иллюстрирующая подход, сюда еще следует добавить обработку возможных ошибок (нет файла и т. п.)

Answer (score 1):

Создаёте свой кастомный класс, например, `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject {
    private static final String NAME = 0;
    private static final String URL = 1;
    ArrayList<String[]> params;

    public MyObject(){
        params = new String[количество];
    }

    public String getName(int position) {
        return params.get(position)[NAME];
    }

    public void setName(int position, String name) {
        params.get(position)[NAME] = name;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
         return params.get(position)[URL];;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(int position, String imgUrl) {
        params.get(position)[URL] = imgUrl;
    }
}
```

Далее, создаете **1 массив** его элементов:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;
...
myObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++) {
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.setName(col[1]);
        myObject.setImgUrl(col[4]);
        myObjects.add(myObject);
}
```

Далее, работаете с массивом:

```
myObjects.get(position1).getName(position2);
```

Если вы хотите получить доступ к массиву из любой точки приложения создаете этот массив в 
 классе синглтон:

```
public class Single{
ArrayList<MyObject> myObjects;
private static Single sSingle;

public static Single get(Context ctx) {
    if (sSingle== null) sSingle = new Single(ctx);
    return sSingle;
}

private Single(Context ctx) {
    ... создание и заполнение массива
}
}
public ArrayList<MyObject>(){
    return myObjects;
}
```

Доступ из любой точки по команде `Single.get(контекст).getMyObjects()`

Понятно, что вы можете наполнить класс `MyObject` любыми необходимыми данными в любом количестве совершенно не меняя архитектуру кода.

Comment: Спасибо. А без классов, как бы массив из массивов ArrayList<String[]> можно сделать, чтобы я вызывал сперва номер один из 20, а потом строку и номер переменной? Сейчас я вот так получаю строку и элемент, но это в одном массиве gallery_arr_1.get(0)[1]..

Comment: Технически возможно. Но придёт момент (вы добавите еще полей), когда вы запутаетесь в цифрах :) в общем, так не делают)

Comment: А Вы пример в целях ознакомления не можете привести?

Comment: не вижу, зачем городить массив из массивов, если можно не городить)

Comment: А как получить myObjects.get(position).getName(); определенной строки? У меня же 20 файлов, в них много строк с параметрами, 2 из которых я записываю в массив..

Comment: вместо `position` пишите нужное число (из 20), а записанные параметры осознанно, что надо: имя или урл - `getName()` или `getImgUrl()`

Comment: так в каждой из 20 позиций имеется куча строк, с параметрами getName() и getImgUrl(), которые мы сохраняли из 20 файлов.. Как минимум для поиска надо указывать номер позиции(из 20), номер строки, и параметр этой строки getName() или getImgUrl() ..

Comment: как всё у вас сложно) посмотрите, подправил ответ

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90480/discussion-between-alex455-and-jarvis-j).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать
ArrayList< Map < String, Object > > data;

И создав новый объект Map - HashMap, по ключу и значению записать нужные данные, например, через цикл.

Нашел часть кода с использованием этого принципа, но он не совсем по теме

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/110-urok-51-simpleadapter-dobavlenie-i-udalenie-zapisej.html

UPD: Прочитал комменты, ну тк если сделать как выше написано, можно будет и расширять Map, если понадобится добавить больше параметров и в цикле при обходе можно будет сверять количество параметров, удалять по ключу и удалять не нужные параметры. (Прошу сказать если что то не так написал или понял)